# Faster than light travel??? Would this process work?

Tags: visible-light, time-travel

This first and foremost could not be done now with todays tech- so bear with me.

I have put a lot of thought into the physics based notion that nothing could travel faster than the speed of light...

I always wondered about this scenario. Imagine you have access to a time machine, and you place that time machine into a spacecraft. You set that space craft on auto pilot to a location that takes 1 year to get to. You then set your time machine to one year into the future, and step through it, and then walk through it again 1 year into the
past. Assuming everything works out, you will be at your new location with no time lost,and have circumvented traveling faster than light right? Or am I missing something, such as a possibitliy the time machine could dump you back at your old location with no spacecraft?!

I am would like to know others insight on this thought experiment.

Comment: You are missing one thing: time travel is not possible.

Comment: If you have enough reputation, you can find out more about your idea in the chat room, but this part of the site is for today's physics, (which has enough interesting problems to solve), not about something we never be able to achieve. That's why I would downvote, I'm sorry.

Comment: From what I have read in Hawking's books, time travel is theroretically possible, but has limitations. Hence I have some basis for my question.

Comment: For some reason, I'm reminded of Steve Martin's advice on how to be a millionaire and never pay any taxes.  First, get a million dollars...

Comment: Sure, it's a very interesting topic, no question, this part of the site is just not the place for it, that's really all I am saying.  . You may have read "By His Bootstraps" by Heinlein.  Same general idea as here, I think.

Comment: @AlfredCentauri I think I fear the day when too few people know Steve Martin's genius.

Answer (score 4):

Time travel and FTL are fundamentally equivalent. So if you can build a time machine then yea you can travel faster than light. But based on modern physics, neither is possible

Comment: Good summary! (And welcome to Physics.SE!) In the future, though, could you perhaps avoid answering off-topic questions? Answers encourage the original poster (OP) to keep asking off-topic questions. Thank you though for the answer, and please keep contributing!